# Is relation "xRy iff x^2 + y^2 is odd or y < 0" correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, education, integers, quantifiers

I am trying to figure out what $y < 0$ means in the relation:
$$xRy \Leftrightarrow (\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: x^2 + y^2 = 2k - 1) \vee (y < 0)$$
I figure that the relation $xRy$ is a set of $x$ and $y$ pairs if $x^2 + y^2$ is an odd/uneven number or that $y$ is less than $0$. But what does $y$ is less than $0$ mean in this relation?

Is an $x$ missing in the premise $y<0$ to find the relation between $x$ and $y$ or is $y<0$ related to the other premise? am I just reading this wrong?

Comment: What is written is that $xRy$ is the set of all the pairs $(x,y)$ such that either $y<0$ or $x^2+y^2$ is odd.

Comment: This is a perfectly good relation, the last part just means that every number is in relation with every negative number.

Comment: As an aside, we can simplify the condition that $x^2+y^2$ is odd to simply that $x$ and $y$ are of different parity (*i.e. $x$ is odd and $y$ is even, or that $x$ is even and $y$ is odd*)

Comment: @Gae.S. yes, I understand that part but how is $y < 0$ implemented? For instance, let say $x = 2 \wedge y = -2$. This will result in $2^2+(-2)^2 = 8$ which is an even number and therefore means that (2,-2) cannot be in the set of R solely in accordance to $x^2 + y^2$ not being an odd number. But $y < 0$ is true because $-2 < 0$, so does that mean that (2,-2) will be in the set of R anyway?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek But how is $y < 0$ implemented? For instance (same example as my previous comment), let say =2∧=−2. This will result in 22+(−2)2=8 which is an even number and therefore means that (2,-2) cannot be in the set of R solely in accordance to 2+2 not being an odd number. But <0 is true because −2<0, so does that mean that (2,-2) will be in the set of R anyway?

Comment: @Palif Yes. $P\lor Q$ is the predicate which is true if and only if at least one of the predicates $P$, $Q$ is true.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks for your answer, you’ve cleared it up for me with that answer.